# Chaining router and scheme

Tags: mule

i am attempting to use a chaining router like so:

```
<flow name="Something">
    <quartz:inbound-endpoint jobName="eventTimer"
        repeatInterval="2000">
        <quartz:event-generator-job />
    </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
    <chaining-router>
        <jdbc:outbound-endpoint queryKey="selectMules"
            exchange-pattern="request-response" />
        <collection-splitter />
        <vm:outbound-endpoint path="Something"
            exchange-pattern="one-way" />
    </chaining-router>
</flow>
```

However, i keep gettnig a scheme error:

```
A Fatal error has occurred while the server was running:                     *
* cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element      *
* 'chaining-router'.
```

Now, i've checked and the relveant scehmes is loaded - my schemes are:

```
<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
    xmlns:stdio="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/stdio" xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm"
    xmlns:quartz="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/quartz" xmlns:cxf="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf"
    xmlns:script="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting"
    xmlns:pattern="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pattern" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jdbc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/3.2/mule.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/quartz http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/quartz/3.2/mule-quartz.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting  http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/3.2/mule-scripting.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/3.2/mule-http.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/stdio http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/stdio/3.2/mule-stdio.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf/3.2/mule-cxf.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pattern http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pattern/3.2/mule-pattern.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jdbc http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jdbc/3.2/mule-jdbc.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/3.2/mule-vm.xsd">
```

Am i missing something??

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chaining-router is a legacy router designed to work with the old service element. In flows, use [routing message processors instead](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Routing+Message+Processors).

In your case, you don't need any router to chain stuff together as message processors are automatically chained in a flow (provided endpoints are request-response, otherwise some dispatches happen asynchronously).

Comment: I dont think i've thanked you for all of your replies. You seem to be the most knowledgeble indivitual about Mule. If i could find an updated copy of your book around here i'd buy it in a heartbeat.